# Why does /wp-admin login send me to this landing page?

Tags: login

I'm trying to help a friend access his website after a different developer created it, but when I visit the site.com/wp-admin, it doesn't take me to the typical dashboard and backend I'm used to seeing. It looks like this.

[image]

When you click through all those links, it just shows all the wp-super-cache data and maybe one page of code, but it's all uneditable. What could be the case? How can I find a way to access the dashboard again? Did the old developers hide it so that we can't go in and fix it ourselves?

Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access via FTP or SFTP? If so you could test disabling all plugins. To do that go to `/wp-content/plugins/` Inside the plugins directory create a new directory calle off and move all plugins inside the off directory. See if you can access the login page now. If not you can try the same thing in `/wp-content/themes/` to see if it’s a plugin or a theme causing that.

Other thing to try is to find the .htaccess file in your root folder and rename it to disable it to see if that is causing this behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me try and get into the FTP, I know there's access somewhere.

Comment: @Jackie I hope one of those 3 posible solutions will work for you.

Comment: Nice!! It was the answer to the first half of the issue. The host activated 2 plugins that specifically hid the dashboard from non-admins. So with your advice, I was able to access the dashboard again, but once I was in, it was completely empty. I had to just add one more extra step which was go into myPHP admin and creating a new admin username and upgrading my friend's username to admin status. Tricky, but thank you for jumpstarting that process. I would have been too scared to navigate the backend otherwise. Thank you!!

Comment: @Jackie Glad it all worked out. I'm curious, which were those plugins that hid the dashboard? Sounds like a good security measure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try /wp-login.php instead.  WordPress htaccess by default ignores direct hits to files and directories.  cache plugin will make modifications to htaccess as well. sorry not great answer but i can't comment yet apparently you gotta do this for a real long time to prove your worth.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! That didn't work either, still sent me to the initial page :( I think the original developer covered the backend, ugh.

Comment: looks like you'll need to ftp in like Carlos said to have a look at the htaccess and manually disable cache plugin by renaming directory.